# Passing an operator to SQL in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, postgresql

I am trying to do this

`Model.where("major :operator :major OR (major = :major AND minor :operator :minor)", :major => major, :minor => minor, :operator => :operator)`

which will throw an error

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: ...o_content_view_versions"  WHERE (major '=' 1 OR (majo...`

this works

`Model.where("major #{operator} :major OR (major = :major AND minor #{operator} :minor)", :major => major, :minor => minor)`

but I am worried about sql injection

The operator is passed as a string. How can I do this query and not have the risk sql injection. I am using postgresql, rails 3.2, ruby 1.9

example values:
operator "<"
major 1
minor 3

Comment: You cannot parameterize operators nor column names.  How are you selecting these operators?  Are these user inputs?  If they are not user inputs then I don't think you need to worry about SQL injection.  Ensure your code generates the correct operators and use them!

Comment: they are user inputs unfortunately, and can be a variety of comparison operators.  I should add that I am using this gem... https://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the list of operators that you support, you could check them before passing it into the SQL.

```
supported_operators = ['>', '<', '=', '>=','<=','<>','!=']
raise ArgumentError unless supported_operators.include?(operator)
Model.where("major #{operator} :major OR (major = :major AND minor #{operator} :minor)", :major => major, :minor => minor)
```

Comment: Excellent solution although `ArgumentError` seems more suitable in this case. I like the inclusion of both `!=` And `<>` even though in essence they are the same it seems like it will make the user more comfortable